# Converted image not displaying

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm using this Python library [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) to convert a color image to a grayscale image, as follows:

```
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgb2gray 
img = io.imread('baboon.png')
img_grayscale = rgb2gray(img)
io.imshow(img_grayscale)
```

The code works fine, but the image does not get displayed, why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use scikit-images, but if it works like matplotlib, you need to explicitely call the `show` method.

### Try adding `io.show()` at the end of the script

---

Edit : I installed scikit-images and tried. `io.show()` really fixes the issue (ie shows the picture).

This is caused by io.imshow which is a wrapper arround matplotlib.imshow, and to show MPL plots you need to call their `show` method.

I learned it the hard way, it took me 4h hours to figure out the first time I used matplotlib :)